# error: void type not allowed here

Tags: java, void, getmethod

Q. In a series of statements, move all of the money in Nick's accounts - both checking and savings - to Carol's checking account. This should leave Nick with no money at the end- i.e. both of his accounts have 0 money. There are several ways this may be accomplished. A suggestion is to use one or more intermediate variables to hold the values from Nick's account, then deposit that value to Carol's checking account. Note: you must get the values from Nick's account by calling the methods defined in the BankAccount class.Print out a report of the checking and savings information on both Nick's and Carol's accounts using the appropriate method in the BankAccount class.

A.

public class BankAccount{

```
  private String name;
  private int checkMoney;
  private int saveMoney;

   public BankAccount(String who, int checking, int saving){
     name = who;
     checkMoney = checking;
     saveMoney = saving;
  }

   public String getAccountName(){
     return name;
   }

   public int getCheckMoney(){
     return checkMoney;
   }

   public int getSaveMoney(){
     return saveMoney;
   }

   public void makeCheckingDeposit(int amt){
       checkMoney = checkMoney + amt;
   }

   public void makeSavingsDeposit(int amt){
     saveMoney = saveMoney + amt;
   }

   public void makeCheckingWithdrawal(int amt){
    if(checkMoney >= amt)
     checkMoney = checkMoney - amt;
   }

   public void makeSavingsWithdrawal(int amt){
    if(saveMoney >= amt)
     saveMoney = saveMoney - amt;
   }

   //prints name and both account balances to the console
   public void printReport() {
     System.out.println(name + " checking: " + checkMoney + " savings: " + saveMoney);
   }
```

}

1. public class BankingDriver {
2. public static void main (String [] args) {
3. BankAccount nicksAcct = new BankAccount("Nick", 450, 550);
4. BankAccount carolsAcct = new BankAccount("Carol", 600, 700);
5. int nicksCheckingMoney = nicksAcct.getCheckMoney();
6. int nicksSaveMoney = nicksAcct.getSaveMoney();
7. int deposit = (nicksAcct.makeCheckingWithdrawal(nicksCheckingMoney) + nicksAcct.makeSavingsWithdrawal(nicksSaveMoney));
8. carolsAcct.makeCheckingDeposit(deposit);
9. nicksAcct.printReport();
10. carolsAcct.printReport();

    }
     }

Line 7 of BankDriver keeps giving me the 'void' type not allowed here error. Can Someone explain to me why it's doing this?

Comment: `makeCheckingWithdrawal` and `makeSavingsWithdrawal` don't return values that you can add together: they are `void` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add the results of two `void` methods together. For example:

```
private static void foo() {}
private static void bar() {}

public static void main(String... args) {
  System.out.println(foo() + bar());
}
```

This is hopefully clearly meaningless. In fact, you can't do anything with the result of `void` methods: you can only invoke the method.

If you want to add the results of the `makeCheckingWithdrawal` and `makeSavingsWithdrawal` methods, you will need to make them return a numeric type, e.g.:

```
public int makeCheckingWithdrawal(int amt) { ... }
public int makeSavingsWithdrawal(int amt) { ... }
```

The value you return from these methods is up to you, depending upon your requirements.

Comment: I understand what you said but how do you think I should go about solving this problem?